# Are there any examples of "par ha'elem davar" in Tanakh or Talmud?

Tags: tanach, korban, sanhedrin

In Lev. [4:13-15](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.4.13-15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), we learn

> If it is the whole community of Israel that has erred and the matter escapes the notice of the congregation, so that they do any of the things which by the LORD’s commandments ought not to be done, and they realize their guilt—when the sin through which they incurred guilt becomes known, the congregation shall offer a bull of the herd as a sin offering, and bring it before the Tent of Meeting. The elders of the community shall lay their hands upon the head of the bull before the LORD, and the bull shall be slaughtered before the LORD.

[sefaria translation]

Are there any examples where this actually happened in Tanakh? What about stories in the gemara?

Comment: Rashi Behaaloscha 8:8